# Compare elements from two lists

Tags: haskell

I’m doing my homework in Haskell and I got to a point where I need to compare two lists element by element and count how many elements are the same *and* in the same place: the first element of the first list with the first element of the second list, etc..

Here’s what I have:

```
compare :: [Int]->[Int]->Int
compare [a] [b]= if head a == head b then 1 + compare (tail a tail b) else 0 + compare (tail a tail b)

compare [] [b] = 0
```

I know in advance that they will both be lists with 8 `Int`s as elements.

Comment: You might use this one-liner: `length $ filter (True==) $ zipWith (==) a b`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problems with your code are:

- The patterns: you’re defining `compare [a] [b]`, but you want `a` and `b` to be lists because you’re using them with `head` and `tail`. Just define `compare a b` instead.
- The order of the patterns: the first match wins, so your `compare [] b = 0` should come first.
- `compare (tail a tail b)` should be giving two arguments to `compare`, not three arguments to `tail`. `compare (tail a) (tail b)`.

All told:

```
compare :: [Int] -> [Int] -> Int
compare [] _ = 0
compare a b =
    if head a == head b then
        1 + compare (tail a) (tail b)
    else
        compare (tail a) (tail b)
```

And although it probably isn’t suitable for homework, it might be fun to know that you can write this by getting a list of booleans indicating whether certain positions are equal, filtering them to only true values, and getting the resulting length:

```
compare a = length . filter id . zipWith (==) a

-- this works too
compare a = sum . fromEnum . zipWith (==) a
```

Comment: Ambiguous variable occurrence "compare"
*** Could refer to: Main.compare Hugs.Prelude.compare

I got this error now.

Comment: @KostasThanasis: That means you’ve defined `compare` in the `Main` (default) module of your program, but `Hugs.Prelude` (which is the portion of the standard library that is imported by default) already defines a function named `compare`, so when you use `compare`, the compiler can’t tell which one you mean. You can: 1. say `import Prelude hiding (compare)` (at least in GHC Haskell—I don’t know about Hugs), 2. rename `compare` to something else, or 3. use the fully qualified name `Main.compare` when you call the function.

Answer (score 2):

You could `zip` the two lists and then compare on the resulting tuples lists
`map (uncurry compare) $ zip l1 l2` assuming you have two lists `l1` and `l2`

and to count all places where they have the same elements

`length $ filter (== EQ) $ map (uncurry compare) $ zip l1 l2`